# Decode content from httplib GET

Tags: python, http, encoding

I'm fetching a simple HTTP plain-text that is in CP-1250 (I can't influence that) and would like to decode it, process it per line and eventually save it as UTF-8.

The first part is causing me problems.  After I get the raw data using `response.read()`, I'm passing it to a reader created by `getreader("cp1250")` from codecs library.  I expect to get a StreamReader instance and simply call `readlines` to have a list of byte strings.

```
import codecs
import httplib

# nothing unusual
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('server')
conn.request('GET', '/')
response = conn.getresponse()
content = response.read()

# the painful part
sr = codecs.getreader("cp1250")(content)
lines = sr.readlines()      # d'oh!
```

But after the call to `readlines` I only get yells echoing from somewhere deep inside codecs:

```
[...snip...]
  File "./download", line 123, in _parse
    lines = sr.readlines()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 588, in readlines
    data = self.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 471, in read
    newdata = self.stream.read()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

My `print`s confirm that `sr` is instance of StreamReader; it confuses me that the object seemed to initialize well but now fails to execute the readlines ... what is missing here?

Or is the library trying to cryptically tell me that the data is corrupted (not CP-1250)?

**Edit**: As jorispilot suggests, `unicode(content, encoding="cp1250")` works, so I'll probably stick with that for my solution.  However, I'd still like to know what was wrong with my usage of codecs library.

Comment: Have you tried to use _unicode(content, encoding="cp1250")_ instead of the codecs module ? (Or _str(content, encoding="cp1250")_ in python3.)

Comment: Besides, the _unicode_ function will clearly tell you if the data is CP-1250 corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html, `getreader()` returns a `StreamReader`. This must be passed a stream, which implements the `read()` function, not, as you are doing, a string.

To fix this, don't read the data from `response`, but pass it directly to the `StreamReader`, as below.

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('server')
conn.request('GET', '/')
response = conn.getresponse()

reader = codecs.getreader("cp1250")(response)
lines = sr.readlines()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
utf8_lines = []
for line in content.split('\n'):
   line = line.strip().decode('cp1250')
   utf8_lines.append(line.encode('utf-8'))
```